# how to put coding in this blade file top?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i use @stack and @push in my blade file.but it not works,because @stack works in layout blade,it not works in a section blade

```
@stack('test-section')

this is test section

@push('test-section')
    this is test put
@endpush
```

i just want to make a section have default data,for example

```
@extends('body')
@section('content')
@stack('test-section')

this is test section{{$top}}

@endsection

@push('test-section')
    this is test put
    @php
        $top = $top??'this top';
    @endphp
@endpush
```

`$top` is ok when `$top` declared in this blade top.my idea from shopify's liquid {% schema %}

yes,it's not necessary ,the section data need declared in the section top,if i declared in the section top,code will become poorly managed

```
@extends('body')
@section('content')
    @php
        $top = $top??'this top';
        $top1 = $top??'this top';
        $top2 = $top??'this top';
        $top3 = $top??'this top';
        $top3 = $top??'this top';
        $top4 = $top??'this top';
        $top5 = $top??'this top';
        $top6 = $top??'this top';
        $top7 = $top??'this top';
        ...
    @endphp

    this is test section{{$top}}

@endsection
```

this is my first question in stack-overflow,I need help.Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use `@section ... @endsection` instead of `@stack/@push`? What's the use case for this?!

Comment: because my coding is writing in `@section ... @endsection`

Comment: Since this seems to be in the same blade file, there really is no need to push, why don't you just put the code from your push inside your section?! I'm not getting what you're after.

Comment: yes,it's not necessary ,the section data need declared in the section top,if i declared in the section top,code will become poorly managed`@extends('body')
@section('content')
    @php
        $top = $top??'this top';
        $top1 = $top??'this top';
        $top2 = $top??'this top';
        $top3 = $top??'this top';
        $top3 = $top??'this top';
        $top4 = $top??'this top';
        $top5 = $top??'this top';
        $top6 = $top??'this top';
        $top7 = $top??'this top';
        ...
    @endphp

    this is test section

@endsection`